# Adding a Text Form to Component View Joomla 3

Tags: php, sql, forms, joomla, textfield

I am creating a simple submit form on my component’s view.  Here is the setup:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$newValue = $jinput->get('newValueSubmit');

?>
```

Here is the form that I have created in the view:

```
<div style="position:relative; top:173px; left:357px;">

    <label for="newValue" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><h1>Enter</h1></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="position:relative; top:120px; height:350px; width:950px; left:450px;">
<div style="position:relative; left:120px; width:950px;>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
<input id="newValueSubmit" name="newValueSubmit" type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-success" placeholder="Value"/>
<button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</button>

</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>


<?
  $data =new stdClass();
  $data->id = '';
  $data->request = $newValue;
  JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__mytable', $data);

?>
```

So my attempt was to have the user enter a value in the text field and then click the submit button to post it in the results.  The value would then be placed in the `'#__mytable'` location for `newValue` column entry.  This is not working.

There must be a better way to do this. Do I need to create a new view that the form directs the values to?  This may be preferable considering the overall project architecture. Either way, how can I get the user submitted value into the database?

---

UPDATED:  I have updated the script to include recent change suggestions.

---

UPDATED:  Updated Request to Jinput due to Joomla 3

Comment: Do you have a modal and controller for you component? Any data that is processed should be put in the modal file. Joomla uses MVC which is what I recommend you also stick to. If this is a little too extreme, then you could always create a module rather than a component and embed it in an article. I personally have found writing modules far more easier than components

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, I will move the functions into the model and controller displays for this and see if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   $newValue = JRequest::getVar('newValue');

   $data =new stdClass();
   $data->id = '';
   $data->newvalue = $newValue;
   JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__mytable', $data);
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it is not getting inserted... I just replaced the block after the form that starts with the `isset` call.  Is that where you intended it to go?

Comment: I just updated the question to better reflect the attempt made here.

Comment: ok.. I have reviewed further and see that each time it reloads the page, the view submits a new entry into the database.  So, a connection is made, but it lacks control.

Comment: Joomla 3.x = Do not use `JRequest`! please updated you answer with correct coding standards

Comment: @Lodder thanks, I have updated the question with your edits.  Still having trouble getting the view to refresh on the same page.